# How to add NavigationBar with Editbutton on left to the Uitable In Iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, navigationbar

In my iphone application i have added the Uitable view. While launching the application the table is showing the No. of rows which I want. Now I want to add the Navigation bar to the UiTable, also I want to add the edit button on the left side of the navigation bar.

How to add the Navigation bar in the UiTable view in iphone? I don't want to use the UiNavigation Based application. I want to add using the code.
If anybody has any useful code or any other useful link or other solution,which would be appreciated.
Please be needful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy assuming you have your list managed by a `UITableViewController`, and aslo bite down ont he bullet and actually use the `UINavigationController` as you should. Then override your `viewDidLoad` as this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];
}
```

If you for some strange reason really do need to use your own `UINavigationBar`, then you have to add some extra code. Perhaps something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UINavigationBar* navBar = self.myOwnStupidNavigationBar;
  UINavigationItem* navItem = self.navigationItem;
  navItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];
  navbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
}
```

But think not twice, but ten times over, if you really have a good reason not to use `UINavigationController` that gives you **allot** of nice functionality for free.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply.Its really nice advice from u r side,which would really help me in my thinking process at other side.

Comment: If your table is in UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, you will also need to implement the setEditing delegate method.